# Where to Start with Text Classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, natural-language

I think the solution I've to use is text classification, but I'm a total newbie and so I'm asking this community to give me some help.

What I've is a very big amount of documents and about 60% of these documents were classified with CPV codes, please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Procurement_Vocabulary

I want to develop a system that classifies automatically the rest (40%) of the documents with CPV codes. The classification should be based on the text of the document, because if a human reads the text then he knows which CPV code should be added to this document.

What is the best technology to use here?
How do I start and are there good resources for this?

I should point out again that I'm a total newbie with Python and ML but an experienced developer (since 2001) but in the past was only developing with ColdFusion, Java, Groovy/Grails, Ruby, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common practice is to represent the documents as vectors, train a classifier on the train set (the labeled documents), and then use the classifier to predict the label for the new documents.

You can represent the documents as vectors by transforming them as bag of words: the length of the vector is the size of the vocabulary, each column corresponds to a word and the value in a column is the number of occurrences of the word in the document. When applied for all documents, you have a matrix where each row is a document.

You can then use any classifier you want, for instance a Naive Bayes classifier.

If using Python, the [scikit-learn's tutorial on text data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll have a look at it and will try.